# Should I sell all Spritnite materials to the Magic Consortium?

Tags: i-am-setsuna

In the recently released JRPG *I Am Setsuna*, you acquire magic called *Spritnite*, by selling materials gathered from defeated enemies to the Magic Consortium.

Over the course of the game, you can amass quite a stockpile of these materials, probably more than enough to buy every Spritnite for every character.

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to selling only just enough materials to the Consortium to buy the Spritnite you are after, or should I just sell them all each time I visit the vendor?

I'd prefer answers that avoid spoilers if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All white materials are your source of income. You will not need them for anything else. In I Am Setsuna monsters drop items instead of gp.